# ActivityとFragmentの違いについて

Tags: java, android

### 分からないこと

Fragmentを用いた遷移でも、Activity.javaはアプリの1つの画面に対して1つ必要という情報をネットで見たのですが、その意味がよく分かりませんでしたので、解説が欲しく質問させて頂きました。
Androidアプリを作成していて、今まではbuttonを用いたActivity間の遷移をさせていました。
しかし、bottomnavigationviewを用いたFragment間での遷移に変更しました。つまり、MainAcitivity.java一つと*Fragment.javaが3つという状態です。

そこで今まで用いていたActivity内にあったデータ受け渡し等の機能やfindviewなどをFragmentに移そうと考えてネットで調べていたら、上記の情報がありました。
Fragment.javaを用いて画面遷移する場合Activity.javaは必要ないのではと思い、上記の説明の意味がよく分かりませんでした。

[image]

### 参考にしたサイト

https://teratail.com/questions/124691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fragment.javaを用いて画面遷移する場合Activity.javaは必要ないのではと思い、上記の説明の意味がよく分かりませんでした。

Fragmentで画面遷移をするのに、「Activityは**使う必要はない**」ですが、「Activityは**作る必要はない**」ではありません。

Activityは、他のアプリケーションから呼び出されるために必要です。
大抵のアプリケーションは、ホームアプリから起動されるわけで、そのような意味では(ホームアプリから呼び出されるために)Activityは必要になります。

通常、Activityを作り、Activityに作ったViewを割り当てます。
Activityを使った画面遷移というのは、前のActivity(当然割り当てたViewも含む)を削除し、新しいActivity(並びにView)を作り直す、言い直すと、「Activityを入れ替える」事になります。
実にシンプルですが、シンプル故に細かい制御ができません。

そこで、Activityで行っていた「入れ替え」を、View単位で行えるようにしたのがFragmentです。
View単位ですので、個々のViewにそれぞれ別のFragmentを割り当てることもできますし、複数あるView(に割り当てられているFragment)のうち一つのみを入れ替えることもできます。

Fragmentの説明を簡単に説明しましたが、いかがですか。

Comment: Fragmentの説明ありがとうございます！
つまり、Fragment間の遷移する場合でも、1つのxmlに対して1つずつのFragment.javaとActivity.javaの作成が必要ということでしょうか。

Comment: いいえ、「xmlとかFragmentとか関係なしに」Activityの作成が必要、という事です。(特別なことがなければ)

Comment: 最低でもMainActivity1つは必要ということは理解しています。つまり、最低限、MainActivityがあれば、Fragment間の遷移も成り立つということでしょうか。
単純に、Activityの数とxmlの数は同じである必要はないのかなという質問でした。すみません。

Comment: うーん、質問とは関係ないので指摘はしなかったのですけど、やっぱりしたほうがいいのかな。レイアウトxmlの事は抜きで考えたほうがいいと思います。というのも、レイアウトxmlはViewの作成をプログラムコードの代わりに記述子たものです。言ってしまえば、(あくまで極論ですが)レイアウトxmlなんてなくたっていいんですよ。だから「xmlの数は」と言われると、なんとも答えづらいです。やり方次第で何とでもなるんです。

Comment: そうだったんですね。
参考にしながら色々調べて分かったと思います！ありがとうございます！